# Jacoco data file not readable for Android on TeamCity

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity, android-gradle-plugin

I´m learning TeamCity Integration Server today and I´m trying yo enable Jococo Reports with my Android Gradle based Application.

[This](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/JaCoCo) document shows me how to enable Jococo coverage, with the following warning:

**Make sure your tests run in the fork=true mode. Otherwise the coverage data may not be properly collected.**

I don´t know what should I do to "run my tests in fork=true mode". TeamCity isn´t generating coverage reports and is warning me with the following log:

> Jacoco data file path specified as C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\JACOCO5884661263301729570coverage\jacoco.exec but is not readable. Coverage will not be collected.

I think that this warning is related to not running the test in **fork=true** mode.

So, my question is:

1. What **fork=true** mode means and
2. **How to enable it at gradle**?

Thanks!!!

Comment: We have changed misleading 'fork=true' statement. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, I was able to instruct Teamcity to process coverage reports generated by *jacoco* using "services message" technique, explained on [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/JaCoCo):

> Since TeamCity 9.0, TeamCity is able to parse JaCoCo coverage data and generate a report using a service message of the following format:
>
> `##teamcity[jacocoReport dataPath='<path to jacoco.exec file>']`

So, I modified my build.gradle file adding the folowing lines to `jacocoTestReport` section:

```
if (project.hasProperty("teamcity")) {
    println '##teamcity[jacocoReport dataPath=\'app/build/jacoco/testDebug.exec\' includes=\'com.mynamespace.myproject.*\' excludes=\'**/R.class **/R$*.class **/*$ViewInjector*.* **/BuildConfig.* **/Manifest*.*\']'
}
```

After that, the complere `jacocoTestReport` was:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)

    executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testDebug.exec')
    if (project.hasProperty("teamcity")) {
        println '##teamcity[jacocoReport dataPath=\'app/build/jacoco/testDebug.exec\' includes=\'com.mynamespace.myproject.*\' excludes=\'**/R.class **/R$*.class **/*$ViewInjector*.* **/BuildConfig.* **/Manifest*.*\']'
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

}
```

And the Teamcity started to report CodeCoverage as belows:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't take into account the connectedAndroidTest results. Any idea of how to include them in the report?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the Gradle [jacoco plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html). This has the added benefit of removing any dependency on a CI infrastructure, allowing you do run coverage reports of developer machines.

Comment: Actually, I´m already using jacoco plugin with Gradle and I´m able to run coverage test on developers machines. But, I would like to run then at CI server to be able reject a build if the amount out "tested code" decreases.